# "Division by zero" PHP

Tags: php

What could be the cause of this error? I already check it with if/else statement in the first level. How can it still show the "Division by zero" error?

```
if($sum != 0) {
    $percent = (($sum / $tss) * 100);
} else {
    $percent = 0;
}
```

Comment: `$tss` equals 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check `$sum`. You should be checking `$tss`.

Comment: "$tss" is always a number between 1 and 200. It can never be zero. Despite this, I cannot understand how it works.

Comment: Well `$tss` is the only variable your code divides by. If it can't be 0, the error is not in the code you posted.